# Kdenlive crashes on render installed from snap store

Tags: fedora, snap, kdenlive

I've recently installed kdenlive on fedora 35 using the snap store.

The issue is that when i try to render a video it crashes with error:

> /snap/kdenlive/48/usr/bin/kdenlive: symbol lookup error:
> /snap/kdenlive/48/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libKF5Purpose.so.5:
> undefined symbol:
> *ZN10KJsonUtils20readTranslatedStringERK11QJsonObjectRK7QStringS5*

I've tried searching the error but with no success.

The appimage doesn't crash when rendering rather then the one installed tru the snap store.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it by installing the Flatpak version.